# Error when trying to access variables in the GRASS startup program

Tags: grass-gis

I am able to create a new location using the Location Wizard, however I would like to create a GRASS location in a Python script, so I was figuring out this can be done from the console.

In the Grass startup webpage it says that this can be done with grass command. I tested grass -v, grass74 -v and grass76 -v, but message from the console is always the same "Der Befehl "grass" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden" (the command "grass" is not correclty written or cannot be found).

I googled this and found that the problem might be due to spaces or special characters in the path, so I reinstalled GRASS in C:\GRASS_GIS_76. This did not solve the problem.

My OS system is Windows 10 and I installed GRASS GIS 7.6.1 (new stable).

What could I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding C:\GRASS_GIS_76 to the path of the environmental variables.